# Why isn't an arrayList entry being created?

Tags: java, arraylist

What I am trying to accomplish is a school project where I create an object and then add the object to an `ArrayList`. The code below is to create an object `DocumentsIndex` which is supposed to extend `ArrayList<IndexEntry>`. However, when I try to use the methods `addWord`, it fails.

What is the issue that causes it to fail? Also, will using `this.size` refer to the object created version of the class `DocumentsIndex`?

DocumentIndex class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class DocumentsIndex extends ArrayList<IndexEntry> {
    public DocumentsIndex(){
        super(10);
    }

    public DocumentsIndex(int x){
        super(x);
    }

    public void addWord(String w, int num) {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            IndexEntry value = this.get(i);
            if(w.compareTo(value.word) == 0){
                value.add(num);
                return;
            } else if(i == this.size() - 1 ||(w.compareTo(value.word) > 0 &&     w.compareTo(this.get(i+1).word) < 0)){
                IndexEntry Inclusion = new IndexEntry(w);
                Inclusion.add(num);
                this.add(i,Inclusion);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addAllWords(String str, int num){
        for(String word : str.split(" ")) {
            //strips by spaces
            this.addWord(word,num);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentsIndex swag = new DocumentsIndex();
        swag.addWord("trial",99);
        System.out.print(swag.get(0));
    }
}
```

IndexEntry class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class IndexEntry extends ArrayList {
    public String word;
    private ArrayList<Integer> numsList;

    public IndexEntry(String w){
        word = w.toUpperCase();
        numsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public void add(int x){
    for(int i = numsList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (numsList.get(i) == x)
            numsList.remove(i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numsList.size() ; i++) {
            if (i == numsList.size()-1)
                numsList.add(i, x);
            else if (numsList.get(i) < x && numsList.get(i+1) > x)
                numsList.add(i+1, x);
        }
    }

    public String getWord(){
        return word;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String returnString = word;
        returnString += " : "; 
        for(int i = 0; i < numsList.size(); i++)
            returnString += (numsList.get(i) + " ");

        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"when I try to use the methods addWord, it fails"* - How?

Comment: What do you think `for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {` will do when there are no values in the `DocumentsIndex` object?

Comment: size and capacity are 2 different things.

Comment: I would recommend that you sketch out on paper the code that you have written.  For example, you can draw a series of boxes to represent an ArrayList and draw what the list contains in each box as your code is run.  You should notice that `IndexEntry` is both a kind of `ArrayList` and has an `ArrayList` in it which is likely not what you want.  You'll also see that  you attempt to read a word from an `IndexEntry` that could be `null`.